# JavaScript .Net, DOM not loading, previously did, not anymore

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, .net

I work in ASP.net.Core Razor pages. I have a javaScript code that isn't working for some reason. I've used console.log at different location to see if the site.js is loading, the javascript loads. I tried loading another DOM with a AddEventListner and it works. But this particularize does not.

The Function of the code is to have a navbar which is hidden when the user is scrolling down, when the user scrolls up it appears. At the very top a special css code is applied where the border-bottom appears.
The name of the javaScript is site.js. Which is loaded at the bottom.
I also tried a console.log outside any function and they load.

To test this i have tried this loads`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
console.log("DOMContentLoaded event fired");

});`

Edit: there might be some missing CSS, but the goal is to have the border-bottom being hidden.

```js
.custom - O - navbar {
    grid - area: nav;
    background - color: #191a1c;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    height: 65px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orangered;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
 .custom-O-navbar.top-scroll {
    border-bottom: none;
}
# NovelTitle {
      color: white;
      padding - right: 30 px;
      font - size: 32 px;
    }
  .navbar-left {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   }

 .navbar-right {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
width: 100%;
 }
```

```css
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {
  const navbar=document.querySelector(".custom-O-navbar");
  const sidebar=document.querySelector(".Custom-o-sidebar");
  const sidebarToggle=document.querySelector("#sidebar-toggle");
  let scrollPosition=window.pageYOffset;
  window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=> {
    const currentScrollPosition=window.pageYOffset;
    if (scrollPosition > currentScrollPosition) {
      navbar.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    else {
      navbar.classList.add("hidden");
    }
    console.log('site.js is function Navbar Loading');
    // If user is at the top of the page, remove border from navbar
    if (currentScrollPosition===0) {
      navbar.classList.add("top-scroll");
    }
    else {
      navbar.classList.remove("top-scroll");
    }
    scrollPosition=currentScrollPosition;
  }
  );
  sidebarToggle.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>@ViewData["Title"] - removed</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="custom-O-navbar">
    <div class="navbar-right"> <button id="sidebar-toggle" onclick="handleSidebarToggle()" class="sidebar-toggle">Toggle Sidebar</button></div>
    <div class="navbar-left">
      <a asp-page="/Index">
        <h3 id="NovelTitle"> removed</h3>
      </a> <input type="search" id="searchbar" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search"> </div>
    <hr class="TheOrangeLine" />
  </nav>  <div class="Custom-o-sidebar">
    <div></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
  <script src="~/js/Author.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


</body>

</html>
```